# I have a CSV file with many columns and many rows. How do I create a one column one Excel sheet from Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is my database:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings

This database consist of training data and test data. The training data consists of many features; one column is one feature. I intend to convert each column into a separate Excel sheet.

The following is my Python code that I formulated to convert the entire text file into a CSV. But I intend to convert the entire text file into Excel sheets. For example, the entire text file contains 10 columns, so I want to create 10 Excel sheets with each column separated into one Excel sheet. Can any expert guide me on how to do it? I am completely new to Python so I hope someone can help me.

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'C://Users/RichardStone/Pycharm/Project/train_data.txt')
read_file.to_csv (r'C://Users/RichardStone/Pycharm/Project/train_data.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: You can split your pandas dataframe to your required column/data what you want to write in each sheet using pandas dataframe operations. Then to make 10x different sheets in excel, use the pandas.DataFrame.to_excel function. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sheetnames = list()
for i in range(len(read_file.columns)):
    sheetnames.append('Sheet' + str(i+1))
    
for i in range(len(read_file.columns)):
    read_file.iloc[:, i].to_excel(sheetnames[i] + '.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: I tried. It cant work. It says the error: 

for i in range(len(read_file.columns)):
NameError: name 'read_file' is not defined

For the .xlsx, can I replace it with CSV file? does it work with CSV as well?